# SetSourceData with concatenated range variable and worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, charts, concatenation

This sub procedure is meant to update the source data (SetSourceData) for a clustered column chart. Both the chart and the table it pulls from our on the Project Dashboard worksheet.

This code is meant to run when a change related event procedure is triggered in drop downs in either of the two other worksheets within the workbook.

It is important to note that while this sub procedure works with hard coded cell references, I wanted to make it more robust hence why I referenced named ranges, which can be seen in the Else section in the last If statement. This is the only part of the sub procedure that doesn't work.

I would like to know how to get my VBA code working so it references the source area from the table used to create a clustered column chart.

```
Sub changeSourceData()

    Dim currentMonth As String
    Dim projectDashboardWorksheet As Object
    Dim matchRange As String
    Dim fyMonths As Variant
    Dim monthIndex As Integer
    Dim expandRange As Integer
    Dim chartRangeMonths As Range
    Dim chartRangeValues As Range
        
        
    currentMonth = Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown").Value)
    Set projectDashboardWorksheet = Sheet13.ChartObjects("Chart 3")
    matchRange = Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown").Value
    

    fyMonths = Array("Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar")
    monthIndex = Application.Match(matchRange, fyMonths, 0)
    

    If Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Apr" Then
        expandRange = 1
    ElseIf Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "May" Then
        expandRange = 2
    ElseIf Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Jun" Then
        expandRange = 3
    ElseIf Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Jul" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Aug" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Sep" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Oct" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Nov" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Dec" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Jan" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Feb" _
        Or Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown") = "Mar" _
    Then
        expandRange = Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range").Value)
    End If


    If currentMonth = "Apr" _
        Or currentMonth = "May" _
        Or currentMonth = "Jun" Then
        Set chartRangeMonths = Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(1, 0)
        Set chartRangeValues = Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(1, 0)
    ElseIf currentMonth = "Jul" _
        Or currentMonth = "Aug" _
        Or currentMonth = "Sep" _
        Or currentMonth = "Oct" _
        Or currentMonth = "Nov" _
        Or currentMonth = "Dec" _
        Or currentMonth = "Jan" _
        Or currentMonth = "Feb" _
        Or currentMonth = "Mar" Then
            If Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range = 1 Then
                Set chartRangeMonths = Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths, 0)
                Set chartRangeValues = Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths, 0)
            ElseIf Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range = 2 Then
                Set chartRangeMonths = Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths - 1, 0)
                Set chartRangeValues = Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths - 1, 0)
            ElseIf Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range = 3 Then
                Set chartRangeMonths = Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths - 2, 0)
                Set chartRangeValues = Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths - 2, 0)
            ElseIf Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range = 4 Then
                Set chartRangeMonths = Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths - 3, 0)
                Set chartRangeValues = Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Resize(Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE").Rows.Count + expandRange - 1).Offset(fyMonths - 3, 0)
            End If
    End If
    

    If currentMonth = "Apr" Then
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'!$F$57,'Project Dashboard'!$H$57:$S$57")
    ElseIf currentMonth = "May" Then
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'!$F$57:$F$58,'Project Dashboard'!$H$57:$S$58")
    ElseIf currentMonth = "Jun" Then
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'!$F$57:$F$59,'Project Dashboard'!$H$57:$S$59")
    Else
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'! & chartRangeMonths.Address & ,'Project Dashboard'! & chartRangeMonths.Address & ")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual specific problem you're having with the code you posted? "Doesn't work" doesn't give us much idea.

Comment: What the difference between `matchRange` and  `currentMonth` ? Are they not both the value in the named range `CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown`

Comment: Tim, the source data isn't selected for my graph when I action a change that uses the concatenated code above

Comment: CDP1802, CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown is a named range in my document and not a variable. matchRange is a varibale i have defined as a string which I used to obtain the value of the named range.

Comment: You have `If Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range = 1 Then`. Is `Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range` not the name of the range  ? since you also have `ThisWorkbook.Names("Profile_Of_Income_Data_Source_Range")`.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the range by the period number i.e. 1 for Apr, 12 for Mar

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub changeSourceData()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range
    Dim fyMonths, mth As String, fpno As Long
    
    ' convert month name to period 1 to 12
    fyMonths = Array("Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar")
    mth = Range("CoverWorksheet_Current_Month_DropDown").Value
    fpno = Application.Match(mth, fyMonths, 0)
    If vbNo = MsgBox("Period is " & fpno & " (" & mth & "), continue ?", _
              vbYesNo, "Confirm") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' expand ranges by number of periods
    Set rng1 = Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER")
    Set rng2 = Range("Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE")
    Set rng3 = rng1.Resize(fpno).Offset(1)
    Set rng4 = rng2.Resize(fpno).Offset(1)
    
    Set cht = Sheets("Project Dashboard").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=Application.Union(rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4)

    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems like the issue might be with the `Offset` method in the `Else` part of your last `If` statement. The `Offset` method requires numeric arguments, but you’re providing `fyMonths`, which is an array of strings.

Also, in the last part of your code where you’re setting the source data for the chart, you’re using `chartRangeMonths.Address` twice in the `Range` function. This might be causing an issue as well.

```
Sub changeSourceData()

    '... (rest of your code)

    If currentMonth = "Apr" Then
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'!$F$57,'Project Dashboard'!$H$57:$S$57")
    ElseIf currentMonth = "May" Then
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'!$F$57:$F$58,'Project Dashboard'!$H$57:$S$58")
    ElseIf currentMonth = "Jun" Then
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'!$F$57:$F$59,'Project Dashboard'!$H$57:$S$59")
    Else
        projectDashboardWorksheet.Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Range("Profile_Of_Income_Months_archived_HEADER,Profile_Of_Income_MonthsRANGE,'Project Dashboard'!" & chartRangeMonths.Address & ",'Project Dashboard'!" & chartRangeValues.Address)
    End If

End Sub
```

In this revised version, I’ve replaced the second `chartRangeMonths.Address` with `chartRangeValues.Address` in the `Range` function. This should correctly set the source data for your chart.

Please try this revised code and let me know if it works for you.